# TypeScript how to set key value on a object

Tags: typescript

I got a problem about  set key/value on a plain object.

```
type getAObjectFn = <K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V) => Record<K, V>

const getAObject: getAObjectFn = (k, v) => {
  return {
    [k]: v
  }
}

console.log(getAObject("foo", "bar"))
```

code is really simple while I got error:

`Type '{ [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<K, V>'.`

why I got this error? I mean k has type K which extends string, so I think they are same.how to get correct result?

BTW, the type of `getAObject("foo", "bar")` shows `Record<"foo",string>`,why not `Record<"foo","bar">` or `Record<string,string>`?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA5hwEEDyAjAVhAxsAYgOygF4oAeAaSggA9gI8ATAZykeACcBLPGAGigDUAfAAoA1gC4oZPgDdJ-AJRFBUAEpYA9m3rk%20QgFD7MGvK1jxk6LMElxEqDNnxEoY2UsIqA3vqhQ28ACubAQ%20fn4A2qIAupIyvlAAvvrJRiaMGgA2EAB0mRowwnaWjsDCAEQAZhoa5XzlKACGbOUKCkA)

Comment: Why do you use `K extends string` instead of `string`? Do you use a more precise type?

Comment: @Anton,  Hi this is just a demo I just try to figure out why I got that error and Imagine that object has only one property "foo"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use a more precise type than string I would suggest setting the key to `string`.

```js
type getAObjectFn = <V>(k: string, v: V) => Record<string, V>

const getAObject: getAObjectFn = (k, v) => {
  return {
    [k]: v
  }
}
```

However if you want a more precise type you could do a typecast, it should be safe in this scenario.

```js
type getAObjectFn = <K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V) => Record<K, V>

const getAObject: getAObjectFn = (k, v) => {
  return {
    [k]: v
  } as Record<typeof k, typeof v>
}
```

My guess is that the reason you need to do this is that `[]`-operator doesn't preserve the type of `k` (just my guess however). By doing the type cast you restore the type of the key.

Further on I'm guessing that the reason that `getAObject("foo", "bar")` returns a `Record<"foo",string>` is that the type `K extends string` makes the compilator look for a more specific type than `string` and finds the type `"foo"`, while for `V` it is satisfied with `string`.